# How am I able to show text from user input on column with JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcheckbox

I'm trying to create To Do List that allow user input to text to `JCheckBox`.

But there is a problem which anything shows up on `JFrame` without last part of

```
getContentPane().add(checkBox3,BorderLayout.EAST);.
```

My ideal result is like this.

```
□Cleaning
□Have Dinner with friend
```

How am I able to fix it?
I have attached file of that code,so please check it.

[image]

Comment: You inserted your components in wrong way. The good practice is to insert JPanel into JFrame. And after that  add checkBox components into JPanel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow a sample code....

```
public class FrameTest extends JFrame{

private JCheckBox jb1;
private JCheckBox jb2;
private JCheckBox jb3;
private JCheckBox jb4;
private JCheckBox jb5;
private JPanel jPanel1;

/**
 * Creates new form CheckBoxDinamico
 */
public FrameTest() {

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    jPanel1 = new JPanel();
    jPanel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(jPanel1);

    jb1 = new JCheckBox("Cleaning");
    jb2 = new JCheckBox("Have dinner with friend");
    jb3 = new JCheckBox("Go sleep by 11pm");
    jb4 = new JCheckBox("Wake Up by 6am");
    jb5 = new JCheckBox();

    try {

        if(jb5.getText() == null || "".equals(jb5.getText())){
            jb5.setText(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());
        }
        jPanel1.add(jb1);
        jPanel1.add(jb2);
        jPanel1.add(jb3);
        jPanel1.add(jb4);
        jPanel1.add(jb5);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
   pack();
} 

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new FrameTest().setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.
I'll try to write this.

Answer (score 0):

You have set your JPanel layout to **GridLayout**, then adding elements like if you your using **BorderLayout** which is wrong.

set your Jpanel's Layout to **FlowLayout** :

```
p.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

add elements like so :

```
getContentPane().add(checkBox1);
getContentPane().add(checkBox2);
getContentPane().add(checkBox3);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me,I'll try to write it!